# Парсинг зацикленных структур на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, циклические-зависимости

Предположим, у нас есть какой-то список:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7]]]
```

И нам нужно узнать сумму его членов. Все понятно, обычная рекурсия:

```
>>> def list_sum(l):
        r = 0
        for i in l:
            if type(i) == int:
                r += i
            elif type(i) == list:
                r += list_sum(i)
        return r

>>> list_sum(l)
28
```

А теперь мы кое-что сделаем со списком.

```
>>> l.append(l)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7]], [...]]
```

Это называется "зациклить" список. Снова попробуем вычислить сумму членов. И конечно же...

```
>> list_sum(l)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
        list_sum(l)
      File "<pyshell#17>", line 7, in list_sum
        r += list_sum(i)
      File "<pyshell#17>", line 7, in list_sum
        r += list_sum(i)
      File "<pyshell#17>", line 7, in list_sum
        r += list_sum(i)
      [Previous line repeated 1022 more times]
      File "<pyshell#17>", line 4, in list_sum
        if type(i) == int:
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Так, и как с этим бороться?

```
>>> def new_sum(l):
        r = 0
        for i in l:
            if type(i) == int:
                r += i
            elif type(i) == list:
                if i is l:
                    pass
                else:
                    r += new_sum(i)
        return r

>>> new_sum(l)
28
```

Запутаем список еще сильнее:

```
>>> l[3].append(l)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7], [...]], [...]]
```

...и уже не работает:

```
>>> new_sum(l)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
        new_sum(l)
      File "<pyshell#36>", line 10, in new_sum
        r += new_sum(i)
      File "<pyshell#36>", line 10, in new_sum
        r += new_sum(i)
      File "<pyshell#36>", line 10, in new_sum
        r += new_sum(i)
      [Previous line repeated 1022 more times]
      File "<pyshell#36>", line 4, in new_sum
        if type(i) == int:
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Вопрос: возможен ли парсинг подобных структур за реальное время? Я, конечно, могу написать функцию полного перебора, которая не будет давать зацикливаться рекурсии, но сложность алгоритма явно возрастет на несколько порядков. Существуют алгоритмы для ускоренного "прохода" по таким спискам?

P. S. Нет, это чисто теоретическая задача. Если попробовать реализовать это не на питоне, а в "Проводнике", то винда быстро выскажет все, что о мне думает. Так что реальных аналогов задача не имеет. Мне просто нечего делать)

Comment: Так, и как с этим бороться? — а зачем с этим бороться? Но в целом очевидно просто запоминать в какой-нибудь Set какие объекты уже встречались.

Comment: Причем не обязательно в set сами объекты добавлять (для этого нужно чтобы объекты были хэшируемы), можно добавлять их id.

Comment: Да, в данном случае достаточно просто держать множество `id`-шников уже обработанных объектов и пропускать их, если они опять встретятся.

Comment: Задача кстати не такая уж теоретическая. Может быть какая-нибудь задача графом с циклами, который нужно обойти - тут точно нужно запоминать посещенные вершины. Графом может быть например карта дорог, где нужно найти путь.

Comment: @insolor В такой формулировке задача имеет смысл. А просто если просто сумму чисел в списках считать, то отбрасывание ссылок на уже обработанные списки непонятно какой смысл имеет. Что это за ссылки вообще такие рекурсивные.

Comment: C помощью вложенных списков можно строить осмысленные описания графов. При том что в графе не будет других узлов, кроме списков. Идеальная модель непомеченного графа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***NB*** Идеи фильтрации и фильтрации именно по `id` заимствованы из комментариев к вопросу.

Функция `traverse` обходит вложенные списки. Циклические ссылки фильтруются через множество посещённых `id` - `visited`. Мало отличается от обхода графа в глубину:

```
def traverse(v):
    visited = set()

    def rec(v):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            if id(v) not in visited:
                visited.add(id(v))
                for vv in v:
                    yield from rec(vv)
        else:
            yield v

    yield from rec(v)


lst = [1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7]]]
lst.append(lst)
lst[3].append(lst)
print(lst)
print(*traverse(lst))
print(sum(traverse(lst)))
```

> ```
> $ python traverse.py
> [1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7], [...]], [...]]
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> 28
> ```

**P.S.** Раз случилась рекурсия, надо добавить версию без рекурсии. Порядок обхода узлов изменился на обратный, но смысл прежний:

```
def traverse(v):
    visited = set()

    stack = [v]
    while stack:
        v = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(v, list):
            if id(v) not in visited:
                visited.add(id(v))
                # stack.extend(reversed(v))  # если нужно сохранить порядок
                stack.extend(v)
        else:
            yield v


lst = [1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7]]]
lst.append(lst)
lst[3].append(lst)
print(lst)
print(*traverse(lst))
print(sum(traverse(lst)))
```

> ```
> $ python traverse.py
> [1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [6, 7], [...]], [...]]
> 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
> 28
> ```

Comment: Красивое решение. Плюсик.